# Unable to reposition monitors on Arch Linux with KDE Plasma

Tags: arch-linux, kde, multi-monitor, wayland

I recently installed Arch Linux (I have used it before), and installed KDE Plasma 5.21.3. I have an external monitor and it is physically higher than my laptop's screen, however, whenever i open settings (Display and Monitor > Display Configuration), it aligns the top edge of the displays together, which makes life very confusing, whenever I try to drag the monitor up, it decides to move the entire window instead of moving the actual screen, which means that I am unable to move the display up. Can someone please point out if this is a bug, or if not, then point out a workaround until it gets fixed, I've heard that something like this is possible using `xrandr` but not sure exactly how. Any help would be appreciated. I did not have this problem when using Debian, and also in Arch Linux late last year.

Specs:

- KDE Plasma Version: 5.21.3
- Qt Version: 5.15.2
- Kernel Version: 5.11.10-arch1-1
- OS Type: 64-bit
- Graphics Platform: Wayland
- Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel Iris Graphics 540

[image: monitor layout settings]

Answer (score 0):

I usually could solve this (inelegant) problem by first mirroring the displays. After both show the same desktop twice you can "unmirror" them and place the monitors where you need them.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug recently causing this, but it is now fixed. Update your Arch Linux system and see. The bug should not be there anymore.

Comment: Updated to plasma 5.21.5, the bug still persists :\ ended up switching over to X11

Comment: I am using Arch Linux btw. At least in X11 there is no such bug currently.